# Create a SharePoint 2013 subsite from another subsite

Tags: 2013, sub-site

I have a subsite, users want another subsite similar to the first one but name will be different. Publishing is enabled so saving the first site as a template is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to powershell, then you can follow the below steps.

1. You need to [export](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx) the exisitng Subsite using

   export-spweb -identity "url of subsite"  -path "location where .cmp file stored"
2. Now create [new Subsite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607579.aspx) using this( catch is dont use the template in it.)

   New-SPWeb http://somesite/subweb1
3. Now Run the [Import command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx) to import it on new subsite.

   import-spweb -identity "url of subsite"  -path "location where .cmp file stored"

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can save Publishing site as template and in case you are not planning to move the template to another site collection then it should work fine.

To achieve that:

1. Open original site in SharePoint Designer
2. In the Site Options set the **SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled** option to **true**
3. Then go to **<original site url>/_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx** and save it
   as regular template